# Count Unique Values Across Columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this

| Camp | User |
| --- | --- |
| camp1 | 001 |
| camp1 | 002 |
| camp1 | 003 |
| camp1 | 004 |
| camp2 | 002 |
| camp2 | 005 |
| camp3 | 006 |
| camp3 | 007 |
| camp3 | 006 |
| camp3 | 007 |

I am trying to get the number of users in each camp that are not in any other camp. So the output is meant to look like this

| Camp | Num of Unique Users |
| --- | --- |
| camp1 | 3 |
| camp2 | 1 |
| camp3 | 2 |

I am trying to get the number of users in each camp that are not in any other camp.
So my SQL is quite rusty but I have tried

```
select camp, count(distinct user)
from sample
group by camp
```

but I dont get the desired output. I am getting Camp1 as 4, Camp 2 as 2 and Camp3 as 2. Can anyone point me in the right direction please

Comment: I removed inconsistent tags , please only tag the database you are using

Comment: When you say you don't get the desired output, do you mean you get an error? If so, note that your query is saying `camp` in both places it should say `campaign`.

Comment: You seem to want to avoid counting `001` for `camp1` and `002` for `camp2`. Does data actually correspond to these mock values with same number endings?

Comment: Also note that your example data has **4** unique users in `camp1` and **2** in `camp2` _Things in the question do have to make sense or we just move on to a question where they do!_

Comment: @EdmCoff Sorry, I have corrected that. I'm not getting an error. The output I'm getting counts camp1 to have 4 unique users instead of 3 because user "002" is shared by camp1 and camp 2

Comment: @RiggsFolly Camp1 has 3 uniques users because user "002" is shared by both camp1 and camp 2

Comment: Ok, but that concept was really not mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems simple enough:

```
SELECT camp, COUNT(DISTINCT user)
FROM sample As s
WHERE Not Exists
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sample As s2
    WHERE s2.user = s.user
    And s2.camp <> s.camp
)
GROUP BY camp
```

Comment: I switched from != to <>, i.e. the portable ANSI SQL way.